# Substitution Cipher in Haskell

Tags: haskell, caesar-cipher

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) presents the Caesar Cipher:

> The Caesar cipher is a primitive method of encoding messages by
>   shifting each character in them by a fixed number of positions in the
>   alphabet

**EDIT**

Since I'm not limiting this cipher to letters, it's not actually the Caesarian Cipher.
Thanks to [Anonymous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42364/anonymous). This implementation is only a *Substitution Cipher*.

Here's my implementation:

```
import Data.Char (ord, chr)

encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode n = map $ shift' n
                 where shift' x =  chr . (+ x) . ord

decode :: Int -> String -> String
decode n = map $ shift' n
                 where shift' x =  chr . abs . ((-) x) . ord
```

Test:

```
*Main Data.Char> encode 1 "AAA"
"BBB"
*Main Data.Char>
*Main Data.Char> decode 1 "BBB"
"AAA"
```

I don't like that I'm using `abs` in my `decode`. How can I write a function (through currying) that will subtract X from it?

Also, please critique my implementation.

Comment: Hey 200_Success, thanks for editing to include the proper tag. But, since Anonymous pointed out that it's only a Substitution Cipher, I edited the title and removed the tag.

Comment: I suggest fixing the cipher to actually be Caesarean rather than just documenting the bug. It's a good exercise. Hint: `isAsciiUpper`, `isAsciiLower` and `mod`.

Comment: I've put the tag back, since it's still Caesar-inspired in nature. As the tag description says, [tag:caesar-cipher] also applies to similar toy-grade ciphers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a legitimate substitution cipher, but it's not a Caesarean cipher. A Caesarian cipher affects only letters, and it's modulo the alphabet size: `caesar 13 "Hello, world!"` ⇒ `"Urzzb, jbeyq!"`

`encode` and `decode` can be the same function (`caesar`?) called with opposite shifts. (Or with the same shift, when it's 13.)

There's no need for a `shift'` helper.

> How can I write a function (through currying) that will subtract X from it?

`(x -)`

Comment: thanks for mentioning that I'm not using the actual Caesarian Cipher. When you say that `shift'` is **not** needed, you recommend just putting the composed function directly in the `map`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `map`. `shift` is OK — yes, you could just write `map (chr . (+ n) . ord)` (as LYaH suggests). It's not necessary to pass `n` to `shift`, because it's in scope.